# Is gmpy2 suitable for implementing RSA in python?

Tags: python, gmpy

More specifically, is the `gmpy2.next_prime` function good enough to find the large primes needed? Or should I be using one of the other many `gmpy2.*_prp` functions?

For example, is the following code good enough for finding suitable primes for encryption?

```
import os
import gmpy2

def random(bytez):
    seed = reduce(lambda a, b: (a << 8)|ord(b), os.urandom(bytez), 0)
    return gmpy2.mpz_urandomb(gmpy2.random_state(seed), bytez*8)

def find_prime(bytez=128):
    p = random(bytez)|1
    while not gmpy2.is_bpsw_prp(p):
        p = random(bytez)|1
    return p

def good_pair(p, q):
    n = p*q
    k = gmpy2.ceil(gmpy2.log2(n))
    if abs(p - q) > 2**(k/2 - 100):
        return n
    return 0

def make_rsa_keypair():
    p, q = find_prime(), find_prime()
    n = good_pair(p, q)
    while not n:
        p, q = find_prime(), find_prime()
        n = good_pair(p, q)
    tot = n - (p + q - 1)
    e = (1 << 16) + 1
    d = gmpy2.invert(e, tot)
    return {
        'public':{
            'n':n,
            'e':e,
            },
        'private':{
            'n':n,
            'd':d,
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**: updated the code with the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I maintain `gmpy2`.

I would recommend using `gmpy2.is_bpsw_prp` instead of `gmpy2.next_prime`. The BPSW test will be faster and there are no known counter-examples. The `is_prime` and `next_prime` checks used to use, and may still use, a fixed set of bases and it is possible to composites that pass a series of known tests. IIRC, someone found a composite that passed the first 17 checks. By default, 25 checks are done but it is a weakness.

I am planning to include an APR-CL provable primality test in the next release of `gmpy2`.

There are specific guidelines for selecting RSA primes that should be followed to prevent accidentally choosing primes that create an `n` that can be easily factored.

Comment: Thanks! I did a bit of quick googling, and updated my code snippet with your suggested function. If you have any more suggestions please let me know :) .